# Auto add all product attributes when adding a new product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

A client of mine requested this weird change based on Wordpress' plugin Woocommerce in order to make things "easier"..

> **Is it somehow possible to have all product attributes automatically
>   added when a product is created?**

Also is it possible to have the "Visible on product page" checkbox automatically disabled if there is no value inputted in the attribute?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

---

**Edit (explanation):**

This is what was explained above :
[image: This is what was explained above :)]

Comment: Can you explain a bit further please and show an example?

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting your query

Comment: As you are using variable products, I think that is some kind of complicated to automate auto adding variations on a product creation, as when you create it, you have first to define (select) what kind of product it is … etc…
May be what is possible to do is: 1) to create first some variable products (without variations)… 2) then with a custom function, add the variations for each created product just as you want.
But this is a real development case…

Comment: It doesnt have to be a variable product,it can also be single product,does that still keep the fact that it's going to be a long dev case?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the way to auto add all existing product variations + terms when creating a new product.

The code *(commented)*:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_add_product_attributes', 50, 3 );
function auto_add_product_attributes( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {

    ## --- Checking --- ##

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

    // Exit if it's an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Exit if it's an update
    if( $update )
        return $post_id;

    // Exit if user is not allowed
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    ## --- The Settings for your product attributes --- ##

    $visible   = ''; // can be: '' or '1'
    $variation = ''; // can be: '' or '1'

    ## --- The code --- ##

    // Get all existing product attributes
    global $wpdb;
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" );

    $position   = 0;  // Auto incremented position value starting at '0'
    $data       = array(); // initialising (empty array)

    // Loop through each exiting product attribute
    foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){
        // Get the correct taxonomy for product attributes
        $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute->attribute_name;
        $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;

        // Get all term Ids values for the current product attribute (array)
        $term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids'));

        // Get an empty instance of the WC_Product_Attribute object
        $product_attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

        // Set the related data in the WC_Product_Attribute object
        $product_attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
        $product_attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $product_attribute->set_options( $term_ids );
        $product_attribute->set_position( $position );
        $product_attribute->set_visible( $visible );
        $product_attribute->set_variation( $variation );

        // Add the product WC_Product_Attribute object in the data array
        $data[$taxonomy] = $product_attribute;

        $position++; // Incrementing position
    }
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Set the array of WC_Product_Attribute objects in the product
    $product->set_attributes( $data );

    $product->save(); // Save the product
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: I see this selects all global attributes in the attributes tab.  But they dont get added to variations tab.  Are they supposed to?

Comment: @Jon If you set `$variation = '1';`instead of `0`,  attributes will be available for variations

Comment: When using this code today, I got a fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WC_Product_Attribute could not be converted to string
in /nas/content/live/contribnews/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 975

Comment: @ZachNicodemous I will try to look at that this weekend

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is using the code snippet from [@LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec), it might be helpful to set another array item.

```
// Get all term Ids values for the current product attribute (array)
$term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => false));
```

Hope it helps anybody.