# Woocommerce Variations Drop-down Empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, frontend, attributes, product-variations

I have an unique project using woocommerce. I created a form with Formidable Forms to add variable products from the front-end.  It's working well with the code below.  I have several attributes that are created.  If the attributes are Not blank, they show up correctly as a variation drop-down option.

My problem is when the attribute - for example "Color" is blank and not submitted.  The variation "Color" attribute is still created and the value is blank and the drop-down is empty. I've been searching for days to solve this issue.  How to not create a variation/attribute if it's not submitted.

I also tried to programically change the set_variation to '' if a custom field value is empty. But that didn't work.

The code was found here: 
[Auto add all product attributes when adding a new product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113840/auto-add-all-product-attributes-when-adding-a-new-product-in-woocommerce)

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'create_product_attributes_variations', 80, 3 );
function create_product_attributes_variations( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {

    ## --- Checking --- ##

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

    // Exit if it's an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Exit if it's an update
    if( $update )
     return $post_id;

    // Exit if user is not allowed
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    ## -- Set product as variable and set quote option --- ##
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'qwc_enable_quotes', 'on');
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'variable', 'product_type', false );



        ## --- The Settings for your product attributes --- ##

    $visible   = ''; // can be: '' or '1'
    $variation = '1'; // can be: '' or '1'

    ## --- The code --- ##

    // Get all existing product attributes

    global $wpdb;
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" );


    $position   = 0;  // Auto incremented position value starting at '0'
    $data       = array(); // initialising (empty array)


      // Loop through each exiting product attribute
    foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){


        // Get the correct taxonomy for product attributes
       $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute->attribute_name;
       $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;



       $term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids'));
       $product_attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

        // Set the related data in the WC_Product_Attribute object
        $product_attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
        $product_attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $product_attribute->set_options( $term_ids );
        $product_attribute->set_position( $position );
        $product_attribute->set_visible( $visible );
        $product_attribute->set_variation( $variation );

        // Add the product WC_Product_Attribute object in the data array
        $data[$taxonomy] = $product_attribute;

        $position++; // Incrementing position

    }

     // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Set the array of WC_Product_Attribute objects in the product
    $product->set_attributes( $data );

  //Save main product to get its id
    $id = $product->save();

    ///////
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
    $variation->set_regular_price(5);
    $variation->set_parent_id($id);

//Set attributes requires a key/value containing
// tax and term slug
     $variation->set_attributes(array(
       ));

//Save variation, returns variation id
$variation->save();
}
```