# Auto add all WooCommerce product attributes when adding a new product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone please tell me how i can auto add all product attributes when adding a new product in Woocommerce and still have the "Visible on the product page" and "Used for variations"-options checked at all time?

I have already looked at the following solution: [Auto add all product attributes when adding a new product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113840/auto-add-all-product-attributes-when-adding-a-new-product-in-woocommerce/49974063#49974063?newreg=0dc23b56648543a6977d9bbcec42f48f)

This seems to work great but what i really need is to have the "Visible on the product page" and "Used for variations"-options checked at all time instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ The post you have linked to with an answer with 2 upvotes contains the following code `$visible   = ''; // can be: '' or '1'` where presumably '0' = off/false & '1' = on/true _ Similar code has been used for variations as well

Comment: Hi @inputforcolor, thanks for your comment which turned out to help me solving the problem.