# How to make a choice of several attributes of a product at once?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Stuck at the stage where it is necessary for the user to be able to add to the cart at once all sizes of goods of a certain color.
Because of the complexity, I decided to try another interaction, how the user can choose, for example, a color, and then 44, 46, 48 product sizes, that is, a multi selection of several attributes.
Or where to dig?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RrUr81o6V7i1a1mz9wat66STxS5mMijG84kovXrl5mQ/edit?usp=sharing

There is a code that allows you to do this, but I can't figure it out.
Let me remind you of vukomers out of the box.

function.php

```
function new_scripts() {
// Scripts
wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.14.7', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.3.1', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'aaa-js', content_url() . '/themes/milena/js/ajax_add_to_cart.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.3.1', true );
wp_localize_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'ajax_object', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        )
    ); } 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_scripts' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_variations_form', 10, 0 ); 
function action_woocommerce_before_variations_form(  ) {

global $product;

$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$variation_ids = '';

foreach ($variations as $variation_one) {
    $variation_ids .= $variation_one['variation_id'].':';
}

?>
<div class="checkbox_wrapp" >
    <div class="checkbox_sizes_all">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-sizes-all" value="<?php echo $variation_ids; ?>">
        <label for="check-sizes-all">
            <span class="option-name">Весь размерный ряд</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="all_into_cart" style="">В корзину</div>
</div>
<?php
}; 
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_cstm_add_to_cart', 'ajax_cstm_add_to_cart' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_cstm_add_to_cart', 'ajax_cstm_add_to_cart' );
function ajax_cstm_add_to_cart() {

global $woocommerce;

$variations = $_POST['variations_ids'];
$variations_kol = $_POST['variations_kol'];
$variations_ids = explode( ":", $variations );

foreach ($variations_ids as $variation) {
    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $variation, $variations_kol );
}

$return = array(
    'success'    => true,
);

wp_send_json($return);}'
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#check-sizes-all").on("click", function () {
    if( jQuery('#all_into_cart').hasClass('active') ){
        
        jQuery('#all_into_cart').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('#all_into_cart').fadeOut(10);
    } else{
        jQuery('#all_into_cart').fadeIn(10);
        jQuery('#all_into_cart').addClass('active');
    }
});
jQuery("#all_into_cart").on("click", function () {

    if( jQuery('#check-sizes-all').prop("checked") == true ){

        var variations_ids = jQuery('#check-sizes-all').val();
        var variations_kol = jQuery('.product .cart .quantity .input-text').val();

        let data = {
            action: "ajax_cstm_add_to_cart",
            variations_ids: variations_ids,
            variations_kol: variations_kol,
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response) {

                    location.reload();

                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This may duplicate of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113840/auto-add-all-product-attributes-when-adding-a-new-product-in-woocommerce

Comment: @Md.MrinalHaque  in my case, I need the user to be able to click on the button and get all the sizes of the product to his cart at once. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RrUr81o6V7i1a1mz9wat66STxS5mMijG84kovXrl5mQ/edit?usp=sharing